# How to get instantiate a stand alone bean in spring?

Tags: spring, initialization

I am new to Spring framework and what I want to do is that I have a bean definition in my spring config which is not referenced in any of other beans and also I don't want it to be loaded using context. I want that while doing bean initialization, spring it self loads it calls it `init-method`.

```
<bean id="test" class="com.spring.test.Test" init-method="init"/>

package com.spring.test;

public class Test {

  public void init() {
    System.out.println("Recvd the call Test.print()  ");
  }
```

}

I don't get a call in this `init()`, I think this Test bean should be implementing an interface to tell spring to load this as well.

Comment: Have you used Spring to call the .getBean() method?

Comment: That is what I dont want to do.. this bean should be instantiated by spring as a callback for an example.

Comment: This may actually help then in that case: `@PostConstruct`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `default-init-method` attribute in father "beans" tag, see my example:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
        default-init-method="init" default-destroy-method="destroy"> 

<!--then you can disable init-method using these tag in child bean:-->

<bean id="test" class="com.spring.test.Test" init-method=""/>

</beans>
```

Adding "init-method" attribute in bean tag is override the father method, like an inherit method. Same with destroy method.

Good luck!